# Hard Seam between modular peices

Tags: edges

Im making a modular bank, and when I copy them in blender there is an obvious seam.

I've tried resetting the normals and not sure how to fix this really.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you need it for exporting to some game engine, and Array Modifier isn't an option, let me know here and I'll make an answer.

Comment: yes im exporting to unity

Answer (score 2):

well, after seeing that both meshes are the same u should really only use the first one using an array modifier.

The array modifier also features a merge function
check the tickbox and the seam should disappear